# Removing display group

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I cannot understand why the closewall() function does not work (nothing happens and the wallNG still remains visible). Generally speaking I need to understand how to handle display group and how to hide them or removing.

```
function closewall()
    print("passes here")
    display.remove(wallNG)
end

local function showgame (event)
    setBox=display.newImage("wall.png")
    setBox.x=W
    setBox.y=H-35
    map=display.newImage("schema_a.png")
    map.x=W
    map.y=H-65

    local buttonChiudi = widget.newButton
    {
        id = "buttonChiudi",
        label = "Back",
        labelColor = 
        { 
            default = { 1, 1, 0, 255 },
            over={ 0, 0, 0, 255 },
        },
        font = "RepriseStamp",
        fontSize = 40,
        textOnly = true,
        emboss = false,
        onEvent = closewall,
        isEnabled=true
    }

    buttonChiudi.x=W
    buttonChiudi.y=150

    wallNG = display.newGroup()
    wallNG: insert(setBox)
    wallNG: insert(map)
    wallNG: insert(buttonChiudi)
end
```

Comment: r u using composer? pls attach more code.

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for replying. I am not using composer, I think it is a matter of logic I have not understood yet. Generally speaking I always do this: 1. Declare a global variable as a group 2. Define a function in which I declare objects and recall the group variable to insert everything, 3. In the button object onEvent clause I use another function I call to hide group. But it does not work. I am sure I pass through the function since I use print function to test it. Why if I I declared the global group variable when I call the remove function and I use removeself() I got nil! Thanks!

Comment: The code above works fine when tested. If you're not using composer to manage scenes, please include the rest of your code.